# How to have `this` point to primitive values in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to write code -- could be a function, could be just a block of code in top scope, just any valid javascript code, so that `this` variable points to a **primitive** value, like a number, boolean or string, other than `undefined`? Not the boxed version of them.

**Background story**

I was reviewing how `this` works in javascript and spent my entire afternoon on having `this` in an arrow function point to any value I want, then I thought it might be impossible to have `this` point to primitive one. Hence this question.

Comment: I don't *think* so. `.call` doesn't work, calling a method on (eg) `String.prototype` doesn't work

Comment: Oh, except `undefined` - that's a primitive that can be `this`, but that's probably not what you're hoping for

Comment: @CertainPerformance right no `undefined` :-p

Comment: @CertainPerformance actually it's possible... No time to check how come, but `[1].forEach(function(_){"use strict"; console.log(this)}, "hello")`. If you have the time to dig this up in the specs... (without `"use strict"` that would be an String object)

Comment: @Kaiido It works! I thought that it creates an object wrapper for it, as `.call` does...

Comment: @FZs yes in non strict-mode that's the actual behavior, as I said, I don't know what happens here and have no time to dig this up.

Comment: @Kaiido Ah ha! The strict mode does it! If you enter to strict mode, `.call`, `.bind` and everything other works as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can.

```js
"use strict";

function foo() {
    console.log(typeof this)
}

foo.apply(123)
```

"use strict" is mandatory, because the verbatim `this` only works in the strict mode. (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-ordinarycallbindthis , step 5).

Comment: Any idea why the `ToObject` in `[[Call]]` doesn't trigger here?

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Looks I was wrong about that, `ToObject` is only invoked in non-strict.